# Bash: Unexpected "(" when none is present

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspbian

I'm just trying to run a simple bash script and it's just not working. The entirety of the script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/pi/akr2.exe
```

Just those two lines but when I try to run it:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

There are no parentheses. How is this possible?

Note: I get the same error message whether I run the script with `./script.sh` or `bash script.sh`

Comment: What is `akr2.exe`? A Windows executable?

Comment: Maybe it's coming from `akr2.exe`.

Comment: It's just a small c program I compiled on the system.

Comment: Does the `exe` run on it's own?

Comment: `chmod u+x akr2.exe` maybe?

Comment: Hmmm no, that would give a different error...

Comment: There we go! The exe doesn't run on it's own. The program uses `system`. I'm guessing I screwed up writing a command there.

Comment: did you try to set executable rights for this programm?

Comment: What does `file /home/pi/akr2.exe` say?

Comment: @Kelly that would definitely do it. You can consider deleting this question and optionally ask a new one if you can't figure out the command (remember to account for differences in `system()`s `sh` and your interactive `bash`)

Comment: Yeah, I just had a command in wrong when I used `system`. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've compiled `akr2.exe` on Windows, downloaded it to a Raspberry Pi and try to run it.

Linux on ARM definitely cannot run a binary compiled for Windows on x86.

When Linux tryies to run it, does not find nor the ELF magic numbers for Linux binaries, nor a shebang for a script, at the beginning, so it attempts to run it with `/bin/sh`. But it's not a shell script, just a binary blob, so `sh` gives you a syntax error and exits.

Comment: Comments on the question from ~10 minutes ago confirm a different cause.

Comment: Yes, I noticed in the meantime. But I think I'll just leave the answer, it might be helpful for other cases. Unless it gets downvoted, of course. :-)